# Оптимальное решение для сохранения фотографии

Tags: php, изображения, mongodb, big-data

Приставим что есть большая соц. сеть в которой пользователи сохраняют свои фотографии.

Какие решения или алгоритмы будут оптимальными для задачи? сохранить фотки в базе данных с base64 или в сервере по стандарту и почему?

БД: MongoDb

Comment: Фотки в закрытую директорию кидать. В базе хранить только путь до файла.

Comment: а если фоток много ? я хочу их обработать так чтоб место они мало заняли. То есть подключить библиотеки какие то или сохранить в ином формате в базе данных

Comment: Для этого шардирование придумали.

Comment: @Riskey для сжатия, обрезки и прочих операций с изображениями есть пакет [ImageMagick](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/imagemagick). Например, так можно уменьшить картинку в 2 раза - `convert 123.jpg -resize 50% 123-50.jpg`

Comment: @MiKeBu спасибо за ваш ответ , я думаю что он самый оптимальный